# Ripple effect on bitmap in imageview

Tags: android

I have images stored on server and I'm fetching those images on an Android device.

Now I want to give the standard ripple effect or "water wave" effect on the images during the onClick event of the ImageViews.

What will be the simplest method to do it? Please provide code if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is quite clear to me.